# jQuery pseudo-class expressions

Tags: jquery, css, unique, pseudo-class

I am using a button to create a new div every time the button is clicked. Ultimately, I am going to need a unique ID for each one of these new divs, but for now I need to change the CSS for certain child elements. Instead of using pseudo-class expressions, is there a way, using jQuery, that I can assign a unique ID number, and use that ID to alter the CSS of the new divs that are created?

Here is my code:

```
  $("button[type=email]").click(function(){
    $("<ul />")
        .html('<div id="friend"><b>Friend Name<b><a class="close closethis tooltip" data-tooltip="Remove persona"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>')
                .appendTo("#drag-area");

});
```

Comment: Why do you need an `[id]`? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create an ID in the first place ..

You can use the `.eq() selector` to target a `specific div` inside the ul..

```
$('#drag-area').find('ul').eq(2).find('div').addClass('yourClass');
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kNu6V/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript any time you're using jQuery.  So you can just create a counter (`var i = 0;`), use that counter in the id (`id="friend'+i+'">`), and then increment that counter `i++;`.